# Is there a way to auto click button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

does anyone know is there any way to click the button automatically in flutter? In **javascript** I use

```
document.getElementById('someId').click();
```

Comment: why don't you call directly the method you add inside your button when you tap?

Comment: in my case I want the behavior of the button UI updating in the same way as when it is tapped or if the underlying tap behavior is kicked off automatically by a bluetooth connection. so calling `button.onPress();` as suggested by Pablo below, answer the question perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

If the button is in a variable, you could do something like this:

```
FlatButton button = FlatButton(
  child: Text("Button"),
  onPressed: () => print('pressed'),
);
button.onPressed();
```

If you don't know if `onPressed` isn't null, you could do this:

```
button.onPressed?.call(); // if (button.onPressed != null) button.onPressed();
```

Or you could do what others suggested, use the same function assigned to `onPressed`, like this:

```
FlatButton button = FlatButton(
  child: Text("Button"),
  onPressed: _myOnPressed,
);
_myOnPressed();
```

Comment: Does the top example of this answer show the button tap animation for you? It doesn't for me. It just executes the button's onPressed function.

Comment: No, it wouldn't, it's just executing the onPressed variable. This doesn't "click" the button...it simply invokes the onPressed callback.

Answer (score -4):

Why do you want that? When simply you can assign a function to a button click and call it whenever you want.

Example:

```
class Blacksmith extends StatelessWidget {
  void _onPress() {
    print('I am pressed');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: const Text('Click'),
      onPressed: _onPress,
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can call `_onPress()` where you want to trigger FlatButton `onPressed`.

I hope this will fulfill the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just wondering if there is a way to click the button automatically before the user click it.

Comment: @TABASCO I think this will perform the same behavior. There is no difference when clicking on the button and calling a function going to perform the same work.

Comment: And how do u get the the arguments from the `onPressed` function if u trigger yourself.

Comment: This is the manual method, not click the button automatically.

Comment: For example, I want to use keyboard shortcuts to activate the button. Other examples might be UX testing... just two examples of why off the top of my head.